# My service won't start when project run

Tags: c#, wcf, service, windows-services

I have a WCF Service hosted in Windows Service, and I installed the Windows Service in my machine across InstallUtil. But when I run my project and I try start my service the service doesn't start.

But when I stop my project in Visual Studio and I try to start service, the service running normally.
I don't understand why this happened.

Perhaps is because in my app.config the service and my app.config the WCFService I have the same port for both.

Comment: that's normal only one app instance is allowed to listen on one port

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start Windows service projects directly from Visual Studio. You need to install them (using InstallUtil as you did) and run them from Windows.

If you want to debug a Windows service, it has to be running and you can then attach the debugger to its process. You can do that from Debug -> Attach to process menu option.

Comment: The problem is, I go to start my Service1 while my project in Visual Studio is running, the service doesn't start.
But when I stop the project and I go to start my Service1, the service start normally.

Comment: @ncampuzano That's because there is already another process listening on the same port. Do you start anything from VS?

Comment: @ncampuzano It's a bit hard to say without knowing what's in your code. When windows service doesn't start, is there anything in the event log?

Comment: The warning say: The Service1 service on Local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automaticaly if they are not in use by other services or programs.

Comment: Hmm, really hard to say without details. There may be an error when your service starts up...

Comment: I believe the error is in that My app.config for Service and app.config for WCFService have the same port.